# SoQt 1.5.0 compile error on Win7 by using VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, coin3d

I try to use VS2010 to compile SoQt 1.5.0 in windows7, but I failed with compiling error:

src\Inventor\Qt\editors\SoQtMaterialEditor.cpp(41): fatal error C1083:cannot open include file:“Inventor/Qt/editors/SoQtMaterialEditor.h”: No such file or directory

I don't change any files of SoQt, but the code version of SoQt only have msvc9, and my qt is 4.8.2. I think maybe the source code lost SoQtMaterialEditor.h.in and SoQtMaterialEditor.h.cpp, so who has this file or the source code that can be compiled?

I have to use this library because I want to do grasp simulation of hand by using GraspIt!. Is there has other compiled methods to compile this library or other libraries that can deal with hand grasp simulation? Thank you!

Comment: You most likely are not missing any files. You have wrong or missing directory in `INCLUDEPATH`.

Comment: My Qt include path is correct, and I do not found "SoQtMaterialEditor.h.in"  and "SoQtMaterialEditor.cpp.in" in  SoQt directory.

Comment: What are these .in files you are talking about?

Comment: I do not sure what .in file is. I successly compile it by vs2008, but do not know why it can not be compiled by vs2010.